# How to fix the Nvidia login issue with ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login

This has been asked many times, and I have tried all the solutions provided, but without any success.

Here is the problem. I out of nowhere got the issue of nvidia driver not being installed, I logged in into tty1 and installed the ubuntu drivers with `autoinstall`

Once I rebooted, the login got stuck in a loop.

I have tried so many different things

1- Purge nvidia-* and install a specific version `nvidia-361`

2- Purge and install from GUI additional drivers (I have 3 options, 384, 381, and 387) they all do not work and cause the login loop !

3- Tried the `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. Same issue

4- Tried `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-current`. No, same looping issue

This is driving me crazy and I am _ this step away from switching over to Mint

Did anyone ever find a special solution that is not written out there, cause I am running out of options with all the googling I have done

I own a EVGA GeForce GTX 970 (if this info helps at all, which I doubt it does)

Answer (score 0):

I am on a bad device so you'll have to fill in the details yourself, but this process worked for me.

1. Purge the Nvidia drivers as you did before
2. Add the ppa `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`
3. `sudo apt update`
4. `sudo apt install nvidia-375 nvidia-settings`

Change the package number to the correct driver for your card

Comment: Did all these steps. Still does not work